# transform greyscale line into a vector gradient with minimal "svg-instructions"

Tags: svg, interpolation

I am trying to create a Moiré effect. I have an svg containing straight, black horizontal lines. My second pattern consists of a black and white photograph, overlaid with straight, white horizontal lines, also in svg format. This works, but the filesize is absolutely horrible, around 5MB, far too much for a website, which is where I want to use this. I've taken a look into the .svg file and it looks like the underlaying image was simple encoded as base64 and embedded into the svg.

The non-white, greyscale lines that produce the Moiré effect are of negligible width. I am looking for some sort of algorithm, in gimp/photoshop/inkscale/whatever that takes these lines of 2d raster data and turns them into an svg greyscale gradient. If possible with configurable tolerance (for divergence from the "truth"). Optimized for minimizing file size.

Comment: This is perhaps on the edge of not being about graphic design? Anyway, converting an image into greyscale gradients doesn't really sound like it would reduce image size. I'm not sure, but I would think it takes more bytes to save a line of pixels as a gradient than as pixels. You mention to let it "diverge" from the truth. Then why not just make the image in lower resolution? Or how about separating the graphics in two? A compressed JPG with the SVG on top? Or simply save the whole thing as a JPG? It's not truly scalable anyway partly consisting of raster graphics.

Comment: Btw: It would be really helpful if you could post screenshot or link to the SVG. If you can't share the image then make an example with a free image.

Comment: How big is the raster image in pixel dimensions, what format is it in, and what file size is it?  Have you tried reducing it's size?  For example: rescaling to fit your web page, converting to greyscale, and saving as JPEG with medium compression.

Comment: Also note there's no one to one correlation between raster images and vector images, and no direct way to convert raster to vector. You can auto trace raster images using software like Inkscape, but the SVG will probably end up bigger in size than if you'd just used a web optimised raster image.

Comment: Here's [an example SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/XBg.svg), 1080px wide, with an embedded greyscale JPEG saved with medium compression. The file size is just over 103kb.